# Powershell Copying files with varying folders in the path

Tags: powershell, path, wildcard

Right up front apologies for my lack of knowledge with Powershell. Very new to the language . I need to copy some files located in a certain path to another similar path. For example:

```
C:\TEMP\Users\<username1>\Documents\<varyingfoldername>\*
C:\TEMP\Users\<username2>\Documents\<varyingfoldername>\*
C:\TEMP\Users\<username3>\Documents\<varyingfoldername>\*
C:\TEMP\Users\<username4>\Documents\<varyingfoldername>\*
```

etc....

to

```
C:\Files\Users\<username1>\Documents\<varyingfoldername>\*
C:\Files\Users\<username2>\Documents\<varyingfoldername>\*
C:\Files\Users\<username3>\Documents\<varyingfoldername>\*
C:\Files\Users\<username4>\Documents\<varyingfoldername>\*
```

etc....

So basically all files and directories from path one need to be copied to the second path for each one of the different paths. The only known constant is the first part of the path like C:\TEMP\Users...... and the first part of the destination like C:\Files\Users.....

I can get all the different paths and files by using:

```
gci C:\TEMP\[a-z]*\Documents\[a-z]*\
```

but I am not sure how to then pass what's found in the wildcards so I can use them when I do the copy. Any help would be appreciated here.

Comment: Why not just `Copy-Item -Recurse C:\TEMP\Users\<username1>\Documents C:\Files\Users\<username1>`? You may need to add `-Force` switch if the destination isn't empty and you want to overwrite items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\TEMP\*\Documents\*" | ForEach-Object {
    $old = $_.FullName
    $new = $_.FullName.Replace("C:\TEMP\Users\","C:\Files\Users\")
    Move-Item $old $new
    }
```

For additional complexity in matching folder levels, something like this should work:

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\TEMP\*\Documents\*" -File | ForEach-Object {
    $old = $_.FullName

    $pathArray = $old.Split("\") # Splits the path into an array
    $new = [system.String]::Join("\", $pathArray[0..1]) # Creates a starting point, in this case C:\Temp
    $new += "\" + $pathArray[4] # Appends another folder level, you can change the index to match the folder you're after
    $new += "\" + $pathArray[6] # You can repeat this line to keep matching different folders

    Copy-Item -Recurse -Force $old $new
    }
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the reply here. This worked pretty well but I am not sure I made it clear in my original post that the destination would have wildcards as well. So really what I am after is to have the files located in: C:\program\users\$domain$\$username$\files\$username$\$programfoldername$\*.* to be copied to C:\program\users\$domainfromsourceopath$\$usernamefromsourcepath$\*.*. As you can see its more complicated than I laid out. I need a way to pass the path wildcards to the path I am copying to. Again appreciate the help here and sorry for not being more clear.

Comment: Thanks again. I tried this and I get: Expressions are only allowed as the first element of a pipeline.
At C:\FileCopy2.ps1:6 char:124
+     $new += "\" | ($pathArray[3]) # Appends another folder level, you can change the index to match the folder you're
 after <<<< Any ideas on why that would be?

Comment: Man Tim you are my hero. This worked awesome. Cannot thank you enough. Tried it with some test files and it looks like its doing what I need. Thanks so much again!!

Comment: No worries. If you don't mind marking this as the answer I'd appreciate it.

Comment: OK one small edit to get this just right. I had to use the -Recurse option for Get-ChildItem to make sure it got all the files. I was moving for the first directory but nothing further. I just noticed this and fixed it and seems to be working. Thanks again for the help. I need way more time with powershell.

Comment: OK after looking at this some more, it seems the files are getting copied but they are not getting copied to the correct location. So for example in the path C:\temp\users\mail\*.*, I would need to have all the files and directories copied as they exist in the source directory. So if this sees C:\temp\users\files\testdir\test.txt, and C:\new\users\ is the starting path and \files is the joined path the script would copy  the 'test.txt' file at C:\new\users\files not at C:\new\users\files\testdir\test.txt. Hopefully I explained that correctly.

Comment: It's probably moving the whole folder before it gets to the file. Try adding the -File switch to Get-ChildItem before -Recurse.

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention I changed it to copying instead of moving like so: Copy-Item -Force $old $new. Its easier to test things that way. I don't think there is a -File switch for copy. But since I am copying then it wouldn't be an issue where the directory is getting moved before the file is getting copied right? The files get copied, just not in the right locations. Its like I need for a whole directory to get copied contents and all in one shot. I am real close here so thanks again for the help.

Comment: At Get-ChildItem... Not the move or copy step.

Comment: Thanks again for the reply. I figured it out and its working now. Need to test some more but it looks right now. My issue was that I was recursing in the wrong place. Was recursing at gci and not at 'Copy-Item'. I am editing the code to illustrate the changes. Thanks again here. You really saved my bacon.